# Have I lost a coins?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I created a GUI wallet and while the synchronization was in progress, I created a subaddress and transferred half a coin to it. But there were problems with synchronization while the blockchain was downloading and the wallet was not synchronized. The question is, will the coins be lost and will I be able to access them if the mnemonic phrase and the key with the password are available to me. But when the wallet was restored, the subaddress in it is not displayed to which it was transferred. Is access now lost?

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, will the coins be lost and will I be able to access them if the mnemonic phrase and the key with the password are available to me.

No they will not be lost. "coins" (outputs) exist on the blockchain, not in your wallet. Your *wallet* has keys you can use to sign transactions to spend outputs you own, that are on the blockchain.

> But when the wallet was restored, the subaddress in it is not displayed...

Subaddresses are deterministic. So just create a new address in the restored wallet and the same one will be shown (if you created 3 subaddresses, just create 3 in the restored wallet).

> Is access now lost?

No, see above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And then in general there is an understanding about the blockchain, but for this situation with the wallet it was not clear